# PHP Curl Login Captcha

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication

I'm trying to do a curl to use a private webpage after the login, the login form call an action to website/entrar/sair/ with the post vars - login, senha(password), lembrar(remember - cookies), g-recaptcha-response (captcha system) and logar. After a sucessful login the page is redirected to website/private (the page I want to use). The problem is that I dont know what to do with captcha, after I get a sucessful login I get a cookie that is valid for next 24 hours. So what I need to do is, when I access localhost/index.php, it will show the page website/private, if the cookie has expired, it will show the anti captcha from website/entrar/sair/, so I can do a manual verification and get another cookie valid for 24 hours.
The code I have so far:

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/teste/ctemp";
$url="http://website.com/entrar/sair/"; 
$postinfo = "login=xxx&senha=xxx&g-recaptcha-response=xxxx&lembrar=on&logar=";
$website="http://website.com/private"; 

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);


curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
```

The post form: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlfZ9.png)

Comment: get the reCaptcha API key from the recapthca div, use it to emulate any requests made by `recaptcha/api.js` to get the value of g-recaptcha-response

Comment: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

Comment: it's probably not worth your time honsetly

Comment: I really need to do this for a project, the API key is the same as data-sitekey ? I tried to emulate all the login page, the the captcha have a red words saying "This reCaptcha is currently running in localhost", if I emulate the data-sitekey, Will I get a g-recaptcha-response that works ?